# Redirect packet that matches a pattern?

Tags: iptables, routing, forwarding, udp, redirection

How can I route an incoming `udp` packet with `iptables` that matches a pattern like:

`53 41 4D 50 5B 79 95 DB 61 1E 69`

from public interface (`vmbr0`) and port `7777` to `192.168.0.1:7777`?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using iptables u32 module. See: http://www.stearns.org/doc/iptables-u32.current.html and [TCP packet filter based on TCP sequence](https://serverfault.com/questions/535435/tcp-packet-filter-based-on-tcp-sequence)

Comment: Please do not just post links - they might get obsoleted over time. It is fine to post links as "further reading", but make sure to include the complete concept, ideally backed with an example, in your answer.

Comment: could you also provide an example for my case? I am pretty new to linux environments and I don't want to break things